# Data persistence through NSUserDefaults

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, nsuserdefaults

Is data persisted in NSUserDefaults between app launches? I want some small data to be persisted even if I quit and relaunch the app.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Yes.

Data will persist in `NSUserDefaults` for the entire lifetime of the app.

Comment: I use it for storing the user's login name.

Comment: Until the app is deleted from an iOS device.  Even then, a restore from backup to a new device will also restore NSUserDefaults.

Answer (score 1):

Data will persist. But, NSUserDefaults is used primarily for preferences. Users expect that it is okay to delete the preference file without affecting their documents and created data.

If the data is not a preference, you may want to store the data in a file inside ~/Library/Application Support/[your application's name]/ instead.

Comment: How would they go about deleting `NSUserDefaults`?

Comment: I believe that he was talking about NSUserDefaults on the Mac. It's easily deleted there, as it's just a Plist.

Comment: @Aurum Aquila Oh? Why is the question tagged as [iphone]?