# iOS NSUserDefaults. How do they behave in the context of backgrounding/foregrounding an app?

Tags: ios5, nsuserdefaults, multitasking

I am using NSUserDefaults in my app and I am unclear about how NSUserDefaults behave with regard to multi-tasking. Currently I create my NSUserDefaults from a settings.plist file in my project the first time the app is installed and launched. Successive app launches rely solely on NSUserDefaults.

Question: do NSUserDefaults persist even if the user discards the app icon from the multi-tasking dock. Note here I do **not** mean they have de-installed the app. Just removed it from multi-tasking.

Thanks,
Doug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSUserDefaults will persist in that case as long as they have been synchronized using the synchronize method.

Answer (score 0):

`NSUserDefaults` data does persist after the app has been removed from multitasking.

See link

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4771560/716216